# Kentico 12 empty MVC site template with page builder and basic widgets?

Tags: model-view-controller, kentico

When creating a new site, the only template for MVC development is an empty one.

With the Portal Engine being discontinued in future versions why can't I find a basic MVC based template that is set up for use with the Page Builder and a collection of standard widgets so I can get started with building content?

The wizard seems to be filled with Portal Engine site templates.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Dancing Goat MVC template that you can install if you follow these instructions : https://docs.kentico.com/k12/installation/installing-kentico-mvc-projects

Also, you can find a learning site that you can find on Kentico’s GitHub account: https://github.com/Kentico/training-kentico-k12

These can give you a good kick start.

Also, check out this video about templates in the service pack: https://youtu.be/-fpA046NXMs